# Angularjs Binding data to other table by check radio button, and update after click button

Tags: angularjs

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="groupName" value="song" ng-model="$parent.selectedSong"/></td>
    <td>{{song.name}}</td>
    <td>{{song.artist}}</td>
    <td>{{song.genre}}</td>
    <td>{{song.price}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteItem(song.id)" /> 
    </td>

    <td>
        <input type="button" value="View" ng-click="go('OneSong', song)"  />
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

<table border="1">

    <tr><td id="Td1">Correct Table</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="editItem.name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Artist: </td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="editItem.artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Genre: </td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="editItem.genre"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price: </td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="editItem.price"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <!--<input type="button" value="Insert "ng-click="addItem()"/>-->
                <a href="#/AddNewSong">Add New Song</a>
                <input type="button" value="Update" ng-click="updateItem()"/>  

            <input type="button" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()"/>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please include your controller with the $scope defined and functions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: <tr data-ng-repeat="song in songs.items">
    <td><input type="radio" name="groupName" ng-value='song' ng-model="$parent.songSelected"  /></td>
    <td>{{song.name}}</td>
    <td>{{song.artist}}</td>
    <td>{{song.genre}}</td>
    <td>{{song.price}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteItem(song.id)" /> 
    </td>
   
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="View" ng-click="go('OneSong', song)"  />

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you provided, I am taking a stab at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/V44fQ/

```
var app = angular.module('songApp',[]);

app.controller('SongCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.edit_song = {};
    $scope.song = [
        {name:'Heartbreaker',artist:'Led Zeppelin',genre:'Rock',price:'.99'},
        {name:'War Pigs',artist:'Black Sabbath',genre:'Rock',price:'.99'}
    ];

    $scope.applySong = function(song) {
        $scope.edit_song = angular.copy(song);
        $scope.edit_song.song_index = $scope.song.indexOf(song);
    };

    $scope.saveSong = function() {
        var idx = $scope.edit_song.song_index;
        $scope.song[idx] = $scope.edit_song;
        $scope.cancelSong();
    };

    $scope.cancelSong = function() {
        $scope.edit_song = {};  
    };
});
```

Comment: I want to use ngmodel of radio button,when i clicked to the radio button the data load to other table. And i update data but only update after click button Update, not direct binding

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, angular.copy() doesn't do a direct bind, but copies the object.  $scope.edit_song = song would be a direct binding.

Comment: i tried to use  $scope.selectedSong[index] = angular.copy($scope.editSong); but i dont know why it still not show data when i clicked the radio button, data not loaded to the other table

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/V44fQ/

$scope.selectedSong doesn't need the [index]